# How to deindex image?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engines, google-search, google-index

I have gallery of thousands of images. All of them at some point needs to be indexed. 
However after some period of time, some of them should be removed from search engine index while they should remain on my site.

My question: is there HTML tag, something as `rel="nofollow"` which ll tell  search engines, to no longer keep in index image in question?

I know for disavow tool, or use URL removal option from Google webmaster tools etc, but that's really not an option in my case.

**Edit:** Just found that i can add The `X-Robots-Tag` to the header of the image (generated by the PHP). But will Google remove that image from image search (because image in question will be already indexed)?

Comment: `X-Robots-Tag` will do it

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the X-Robots-Tag HTTP header will specifically handle this.

Using the `unavailable_after` directive, this instructs a search engine to remove this content from their index after a certain time period.

For example:-

```
X-Robots-Tag: noarchive
X-Robots-Tag: unavailable_after: 31 Dec 2013 23:59:59 GMT
```

You can read and learn more on this at [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

As the title of the question wasn't overly descriptive, for those landing here wondering how to just carry out a straight forward request to remove an image from an image search engine, view the properties of the image from the image search engine to get the original and indexed URL and then just request the removal of that URL from the index in the same way you would request the deindex of any content at Webmaster Tools (or equivalent) - i.e. [for example](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181721?hl=en).